# If $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=1$, then does $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n^{3/2}=1$ also?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I have tried rewriting $a_n^{3/2}=(a^{1/2}-1)(a_n+a_n^{1/2}+1)$, but can't seem to make any progress after that.

Would applying the triangle inequality help?

Comment: the function $f(x) = x^{3/2}$ is continuous, and hence $\lim f(a_n) = f(1)$, if $a_n \to 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The function $x\mapsto x\sqrt x$ is continuous at 1 and use the sequential characterization of the limit.

Comment: Ah. I knew there was an easier way. Thank you. I will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 4):

A direct argument can go as follows (without invoking the continuity), for sufficiently large $n$, 
\begin{align}
& |a_n^{3/2} - 1| = |\sqrt{a_n}^3 - 1^3| = |(\sqrt{a_n} - 1)(a_n + \sqrt{a_n} + 1)| \\
= & |a_n - 1| \frac{a_n + \sqrt{a_n} + 1}{\sqrt{a_n} + 1} \\
\leq & |a_n - 1| (1 + \sqrt{a_n}) \leq 2|a_n - 1|.
\end{align}

You can then conclude with an $\varepsilon$-$N$ syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^{3\over 2}$, $\lim_n(f(a_n)=f(\lim_n a_n)$ since $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is continuous then $\lim_{\infty} f(a_n)=f(\lim_\infty a_n)$.
Using $f(x)=x^{3/2}$ you have the answer.

I think you can demonstrate it using epsilons and the triangular inequality.